# Run nginx web server as a separate pod in the namespace

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have an application that serves static content using nginx webserver, here is how the actual `nginx.conf` file looks like

```
upstream app_api {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://chp_api;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 3600;
    }

    location /staticfiles/ {
    alias /home/chp_api/web/staticfiles/;
    }
}
```

In order to convert this to helm chart and to run the nginx as a separate pod in the app namsespace. I followed this [code](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/nextcloud/templates/nginx-config.yaml).
Here is my `nginx-config.yaml` file

```
{{- if .Values.nginx.enabled -}}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "app.fullname" . }}-nginxconfig
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "app.fullname" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
data:
  nginx.conf: |-
{{- if .Values.nginx.config.default }}

    upstream app_api {
        server web:8000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        # set max upload size
        client_max_body_size 100M;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app_api;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_read_timeout 3600;
        }

        location /staticfiles/ {
            alias /home/app_api/web/staticfiles/;
        }
    }
{{- else }}
{{ .Values.nginx.config.custom | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

The values.yaml file for nginx looks like

```
nginx:
  enabled: false
  image:
    repository: nginx
    tag: alpine
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

  config:
    default: true

  resources: {}
```

But I don't see that the separate pod for nginx web server being created, except the one for the app. May I please know what am I doing wrong, I am new to kubernetes and helm chart.

Comment: looking at the manifests above, it seems you are only deploying configMap, In order to deploy the nginx web server as a pod, you should deploy "Pod" or "Deployment" resources which uses that configMap you just created.

Comment: @saurabh_garg, May I please know how? Or if you could please share me an example that will be very helpful, I am very new to k8 and helm

Comment: Here is example from official k8s documentation
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-configmap-as-container-environment-variables

If you are new to k8, then I would suggest to understand the resources and their usage in k8s before moving further.  A good place to start learning and practicing is 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/

Comment: The values you show also set `nginx: { enabled: false }`, so the conditional around the entire ConfigMap you show will fail and the ConfigMap won't be generated.  As @saurabh_garg indicates you will also need a Deployment to actually run the Nginx server (probably based on a custom image that includes the files you're serving).

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are new to k8s and Helm and the provided repo doesn't explain how to create a deployment step by step I would suggest to take a look at [the official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) where you can learn how to deploy a simple nginx deployment and manage it further.